# Microsoft Access: Query to delete duplicate data but keep most recent

Tags: database, microsoft-access, sql, query

To my surprise, I've been having trouble finding an answer to this question for my specific case.

I have a table with ID and date and I would like to keep only one ID, and that is the most recent one.

For example:

```
ID | Date  
1    July 6  
2    July 2  
1    July 4  
2    July 5
```

Becomes:

```
ID | Date  
1    July 6  
2    July 5
```

I've found solutions for different database applications that use a different version of SQL but I haven't been able to figure anything out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but you can try:

```
DELETE FROM mytable tb1 
WHERE
(Date NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM mytable WHERE ID=tb1.ID)) AND 
(tb1.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table1));
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!